# ExceuteUpdate Statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to update the date into a table using UPDATE statement, but everytime I do that I get errors. I have tried numerous ways but still get the error. Here is what I am trying to do

```
public void updateTeacher(Teacher a)
{
    int f = Integer.parseInt(a.getiD());

    String query = "UPDATE teacher SET (NAME='" + a.getNaMe() + "' ADDRESS='" + a.getAddRess() + "' PHONE_NO="+ a.getPhOne() + " EMAIL='" + a.geteMail() + ") WHERE ID =" + f;

    try
    {
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem in Query");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this I get the following error

> Problem in Query com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>   near 'ADDRESS='Lahore, Pakistan' PHONE_NO=2147483647
>   EMAIL='n.nadeem@bnu.edu.pk WHERE ' at line 1

Please let me know where is it that I am wrong and kindly update the statement.

Comment: you should separate values by a comma .`UPDATE teacher SET NAME='" + a.getNaMe() + "' , ADDRESS`

Comment: Hey you might want to obfuscate the phone number in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't use string concatenation at all, but rather parameterized queries, as concatenation makes the code messy and opens up to SQL injection problems.

That said, the other issue in your code is that you are missing commas between the values you set. It should be:

```
String query = "UPDATE teacher SET NAME='" + a.getNaMe() + "' , ADDRESS='" + a.getAddRess() + "' , PHONE_NO="+ a.getPhOne() + " , EMAIL='" + a.geteMail() + "' WHERE ID =" + f;
```

Read more about how to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Is compiled c# susceptible to SQL injection? Where it is wrapped in a function and they are passing in the "teacher" object I don't see that as an attack vector.

Comment: @JustinHanley, not unless the teacher's name happens to be [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @JustinHanley It's java (not that it matters), and yes, I believe the code is vulnerable. In any case - at risk or not - concatenation sucks, and params should be used in my opinion :)

Comment: @MickMnemonic haha even if it was ;) I think this would still be fine. JPW how could you exploit this? I'll have to do some reading on prepared statements, thanks for the link

Comment: @JustinHanley, whether the code is compiled or interpreted doesn't really matter w.r.t. vulnerability to SQL injection. In this case, if the author of the code doesn't have full control (i.e. hard-coded in the binary) over all variables (name, address, phone number, email) that are concatenated into the query, the code is vulnerable.

Comment: @JustinHanley I'm not sure it is possible to exploit this; it's an interesting question so I'll give it a try and see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks the above statement worked within minor changes in the end

a.geteMail() + "' WHERE ID =" + f;

Comment: @JustinHanley i tested it and the code most certainly is at risk. I used `"x';delete from customers;--"` as one of the parameters and sure enough all data got deleted from my customers table... :D

Comment: @jpw nice, so if someone passes in a teacher with the name "x'delete from customers;--" boom goes the database. Thanks for figuring that out!

Answer (score 0):

Your update query needs commas after each "set" item like below:

```
update teacher
   set name = 'teachersName',
       address = '123 st',
       phone = '800-555-5555',
       email = 'test@email.com'
           where id = 1;

String query = "UPDATE teacher SET NAME='" + a.getNaMe() + "', ADDRESS='" + a.getAddRess() + "', PHONE_NO="+ a.getPhOne() + ", EMAIL='" + a.geteMail() + " WHERE ID =" + f;
```

What data type is the phone number though? That may also need to be wrapped in single quotes if its a varchar

Answer (score 0):

Put a **,** between columns and check the PHONE_NO column, for example, for missing ' .

```
SET NAME='" + a.getNaMe() + "', ADDRESS='"
```